# Visual C++ Redistributable 2013 (vcredist for 2013) platform support for Windows 2016

Tags: visual-c++, redistributable

As per the information published for Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2013, Windows 2012 R2 is the latest platform supported on Windows Operating systems.

Our application code (C++) is built with Visual Studio C++ 2013 and we are using VC++ redistributable 2013 on Windows 2012 R2 platform to work with the binaries which are built as mentioned above.

Now, we are planning to use VC++ redistributable 2013 on Windows 2016 platform to work with same binaries. When I check for platform support of VC++ redistributable 2013 for Windows platforms, Windows 2012 R2 is the latest platform supported and I dont see Windows 2016 is mentioned in the supported platforms list. (Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235435(v=vs.120).aspx)

When I test internally with VC++ redistrbutable 2013 on Windows 2016 platform, binaries are running good as expected as of now.

So, I am assuming VC++ redistrbutable 2013 supports on Windows 2016 platform.

Can you please provide confirmation on support of VC++ redistrbutable 2013 supports on Windows 2016 platform? So that, we can use our application on Windows 2016 platform using VC++ redistrbutable 2013.

If these are any published KBs for support of VC++ redistrbutable 2013 on Windows 2016 platform, Please share.

Please provide confirmation on support of VC++ redistrbutable 2013 on Windows 2016 platform.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the table you link to correctly, it specifies for which platforms you can build software for with the given Visual Studio version. This does in no way imply that the software so built does not run on more modern platforms.

Typically, the opposite will be the case: Old software will run on modern platforms. That's called *compatibility*. I do not think that Microsoft will decide to break (moderately) old software wholesale and intentionally.